# How to send DELETE request using browser in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have to use Postman to send `POST PUT and DELETE` request to my server, is there any way I can hit POST request through browsers directly, using browser front end only

I Have a form that on submits should delete data from my server but using a form I can send only the GET or POST method only I know I can do it with the POST method, but I need to do it by `DELETE`.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to send a "DELETE" request via Ajax, the question should be will your server understand it.

While DELETE is a http method, it's not a generally supported request type in most back-end frameworks, rather you generally "overload" a POST request while setting the action as delete via a hidden form field.

So depending on your back-end framework, you would need to consult their documentation, but generally its accomplished as described above.

As for performing a POST request by URL alone, in a browser there is no way that I'm aware of, you need some tool, to be able to set headers to be able to form a POST request, such as JavaScript, curl etc

MDN has a great introduction to the topic

> The HTTP POST method sends data to the server. The type of the body of the request is indicated by the Content-Type header.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST